# MPI_Abort() vs exit()

Tags: c, mpi, abort

Is there any good reason to prefer

```
MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MY_ERROR_CODE);
```

to

```
exit(MY_ERROR_CODE);
```

in an MPI-based parallel code written in C? So far I've never used the former.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the documentation of the `MPI_Abort` function: https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Abort.3.php. The `exit` function just terminates the calling process. `MPI_Abort` on the other hand

> makes a "best attempt" to abort all tasks in the group of comm

not just the calling process.

Comment: Correct. But in my experience, when one process is aborted, MPI automatically aborts all the remaining processes.

Comment: @Arham: My guess would be that this is dependent on the particular MPI architecture/topology, and not something the API can guarantee happens - it requires a method for seeing the death of the one process.

Comment: Maybe a simple call of exit() doesn't guarantee the return of the error code to the OS.